# Cannot connect to both RDP and SQL Server(Azure) over VPN at the same time

Tags: sql-server, azure, remote-desktop

I have an Azure VPN client that I use for connecting to a web server using RDP and to an Azure SQL Server instance using SSMS.  The problem is, I cannot connect to both at the same time.

When I go to the Networking properties of the VPN connection, then select the properties of TCP/IPv4, if I select "Use default gateway on remote network", I am able to connect to RDP, but not SQL Server.  If "Use default gateway on remote network" is not selected, I am able to connect to SQL Server, but not RDP.

What can I do to be able to connect to both at the same time?

Comment: It sounds like you have not whitelisted your VPN IP (https://msftplayground.com/2017/01/adding-your-client-ip-to-the-azure-sql-server-firewall/).

Comment: If my IP weren't whitelisted already, I wouldn't be able to connect to either of them at all.  I can connect to both of them, just not at the same time.

Comment: When you say web server what do you mean? and if your SQL Server installs in the Azure VM or just an Azure SQL Server service?

Comment: By web server, I mean a virtual server running IIS that I RDP into.  The SQL Server is an Azure SQL Server where the data is stored in the cloud that I access via SSMS, but does not involve an actual VM that I RDP into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know. By default, once a successful VPN connection creates, the highest priority entry will be added automatically in the local machine route table. When you select `Use default gateway on remote network`, data that can not be sent on the local network is forwarded to the dial-up network when you are connected to a local network and a dial-up network simultaneously. The local network prefers to select a VPN connection route. The connection to a local network is disconnected automatically by default. So you could RDP to the web server via the private VPN connection in the dial-up network. You could not access the Azure SQL server since the traffic from the dial-up network is not allowed in the firewall of Azure SQL server firewall. In this scenario, you could check if the outgoing traffic to the Internet from your dial-up network is blocking.

When you un-select `Use default gateway on remote network`, usually default gateway of the PPP adaptor will be empty. In this scenario, you cannot connect to resources on the remote network because you have disabled the `Use Default Gateway on Remote Network setting` in the VPN TCP/IP configuration. You could add routes for the desired VPN subnets. Refer to this paragraph [Configuring Split Tunnel for Windows](https://documentation.meraki.com/MX/Client_VPN/Configuring_Split_Tunnel_Client_VPN#Configuring_Split_Tunnel_for_Windows)

You could use `route print` on the local machine to check the route entry. Compare the route table in the two situations. More details you could get from this [DOC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/317025/you-cannot-connect-to-the-internet-after-you-connect-to-a-vpn-server).

Comment: Update my reply, let me know if you have some question.

Comment: Not sure how to determine what my destination subnet is.

Comment: I think the destination subnet is where web server located.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to configure a service endpoint on your vnet to allow traffic to route through to your Azure SQL database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview

Try the link above for help configuring it.